# Node.js + Express.js + Passport.js - i need some advice how to structure them

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

i found this tutorial about Node.js + Express.js + Passport.js
[tutorial on scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

**i need some advice about it.**

1) local-signup check input data

in this example there is no check for input data for login or signup, for example check if email is empty or invalid, or add a captcha control, so, if i need to add them **where is the better location?**

inside passport.js?

inside routes.js?

in other file?

2) signup POST and GET

in this example i have two route, one GET for render the form, one POST to handle the form submission.

i'd like, i case of error, render the form with error message, but also with all input text filled with the entered data.

if i check the input data inside POST route, when i redirect to the GET route i need to pass it all error message and also the value submitted.

I do that with req.flash?

is better handle GET and POST in the same function?

there is another (better) way to do that?

thank you all for your advice and help

Answer (score 1):

To answer question `1)`, since the extra form validation you're talking about isn't part of passport's flow, I would suggest keeping it in its own middleware, separate from `config/passport.js`. You could define your function similar to how `isLoggedIn` helper that's there already. Like this:

```
function validateSignup(req, res, next) {
    // Perform your field validation and/or CAPTCHA checking here
    if (!verifyCaptcha(req.body)) {
        return res.status(401).end();
    }
    next();
}

app.post('/signup', validateSignup, passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
```

For `2)` and beyond,

> i'd like, i case of error, render the form with error message, but also with all input text filled with the entered data.

The simples way to achieve this I think would be to issue your signup/login POST as an AJAX request instead of doing a traditional form submission, and have your POST route return a JSON result instead of rendering an HTML page. That way your page doesn't refresh, and your form values will remain as they were. In rough strokes, using jQuery your client side code might look something like this:

```
$("#signup-form").submit(function(e){
    // Prevents your form from submitting as usual
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('/signup', $('#theform').serialize())
      .done(function() {
        // Success! Navigate to home page
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Show error in UI
      });
});
```

For highlighting form errors in your UI, that's a whole other story and depends on what frameworks you're using. If you're using bootstrap for example, I would recommend [bootstrapValidator](http://formvalidation.io/).

> is better handle GET and POST in the same function?

No, I would definitely keep these routes separate. Furthermore, if you do choose to follow the AJAX suggestion above I find it easier if I organize my HTML-serving routes under separate paths from my JSON routes. For example, if I have a `signup` route that shows a signup page, and a JSON endpoint for posting signup form to, I would organize it like this:

`GET /signup`

`POST /api/signup`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Andrew.
Ajax and jQuery are a great solution, I am also considering the use of Angular.js for other parts of the app.
For a better organization of the code it's good put functions such as 'validateSignup' into a separate file, as a functions module? Or not.
Now i'm usual to put all logic into a routes functions but it a big mess :)

Comment: If you have a sizable app on your hands, AngularJS would be a good choice, better than pure jQuery. As far as splitting off separate modules you must consider the reason why you're doing it. For example, are you doing it to make your methods easier to find? Are you planning on sharing this code among multiple projects? A "utility functions" module might be a good place to hold generic small utility helpers that are used throughout your code, but I wouldn't expect to find `validateSignup` there.